# Java error while launching JMeter bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jmeter

I am trying to launch JMeter through the BAT file on a windows machine but I am getting the following error:

```
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have set the java path earlier and this was working perfectly fine earlier. can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue?

Comment: How can we assist you without seeing any code?

Comment: Can you please post the batch file?

Comment: I am just launching JMeter as we usually do, not from any BAT file but by clicking on windows batch file that lies in /bin directory when you download the JMeter setup.

Comment: While I am a SME on batch-files I do not have JAVA or METER installed on my systems. Without seeing the batch file code the only people who will be able to help you are people who also have the same system setup as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you there is no Java in the path, which you can check by typing in a command line:

> java -version

So you need to install JDK 8 or 11 , you can choose Oracle JDK or Open JDK.

Also check you use last JMeter version which is 5.0